# Global interception of knockout rendering?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to take a web page that uses knockout and apply a JQuery UI date picker to all date fields (using the HTML5 input type), since the browser in question doesn't support the new type automatically. I've seen custom bindings that I could apply on the elements by hand. But I was hoping to be able to apply the behavior globally without having to deal with each template individually.

Comment: Would you accept globally applying the custom binding? Because this would be as easy as scanning the DOM and adding a binding before you call `applyBindings`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/3W28V/1/

Comment: Interesting idea. That has some promise, and at least keeps me from managing inside the view itself. Good starting point!

Answer (score 0):

Promoting comment of [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/3W28V/1) to answer.

```
$('[datepicker][data-bind]').each(function (i) {
        console.log($(this).attr("data-bind"));
        var attr = $(this).attr("data-bind").replace("value", "datepicker");
        $(this).attr("data-bind", attr);
      });
```